# Parsing JSON error "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a number instead

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am attempting to display data from a fake backend JSON file. I am attempting to gather the data from an array in side of the "shipment_items" key. I know my code is not structured correctly because I keep getting an error
             typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
      [image]

```
       struct Items: Codable {
    var itemName: String?
    var price: Int?
    var brand: String?
    var size: String?

}
//Custom Keys
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
    case itemName = "name"
    case price = "price"
    case brand = "brand"
    case size = "size"
}


func parseData(){
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxx")
        else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                return }
        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            let model = try decoder.decode([String:[Items]].self, from: dataResponse)
            print(model["shipment_items"])


        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear: Please look at the root object of the JSON, the value of key `id` is 5 which is an `Int`, not `[Items]`. This is what *Expected to decode Array but found a number instead* is telling you.

You have to add an umbrella struct for the root object.

And the type of `price` is `String`, **everything** in double quotes is `String`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let items : [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case id, items = "shipment_items" }
}

struct Item : Decodable {
    let itemName: String
    let price: String
    let brand: String
    let size: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemName = "name", price, brand, size
    }
}
```

And decode

```
let model = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: dataResponse)
print(model.items)
```